# Very confused, how and when the arguments of the nested function get called and passed value in?

Tags: swift, function

The code example comes from the [office swift document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html)

```
let names = ["Chris", "Alex", "Ewa", "Barry", "Daniella"]
func backwards(s1: String, _ s2: String) -> Bool {
    return s1 > s2
}
var reversed = names.sort(backwards)
```

`backwards` function had been used as the argument of the method `sort(_:)`. 
The function `backwards` returns boolean values. However, when I tried this `names.sort(true)` I've got an error from the compiler!

Why there are no errors in the example code?

Another question is, what's going on with `s1` and `s2` as the arguments? When did they get called? How the strings in `names` array get passed into them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The function backwards returns boolean values, however, when I tried this names.sort(true)

The sort method being used is actually the [`sort(isOrderedBefore: (Element, Element) -> Bool)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/arrayslice/1688614-sort) method which takes a comparison function as a parameter. The function has to take the particular set of parameters specified in the interface, i.e. a function that takes two `Element` parameters and returns a `Bool`.

As gnasher explained, you're getting an error because `true` is a value, not a function. You could write a function that returns `true` though, and that should work. Using Swift's trailing closure syntax, you could write:

```
names.sort() {return true}
```

That obviously wouldn't be very useful for actual sorting, but it shows how to make your example work.

> what's going on with s1 and s2 as the arguments? When did they get called? How the strings in names array get passed into them?

That's the job of the `sort` method. It's an instance method belonging to `ArraySlice`, and it compares the elements in the slice two at a time to determine how they should be ordered. The actual comparison is done using the comparison method that you pass in, so that you can use the same `sort` method to sort your array using any sort order you can dream up. Try doing this:

```
let names = ["Harry", "David", "Susan", "Alice"]
let sortedNames = names.sort() {
    print($0, $1)
    return $0 < $1
}
```

And you should see a list of output lines as `sort()` calls your comparison method repeatedly.

Comment: Thanks so much. Very nice explanation!

Answer (score 1):

"true" isn't a function comparing two strings. When you sort an array of strings, you need a function comparing two strings.

Comment: That's new to me. I didn't know that it has to be a function inside the `sort(_:)`, I think I get confused by "_:" sign. For me, seems it was waiting for a value to be passed

Comment: `_:` means that the function parameter name is not used on the caller side.

Comment: @Eric D Thanks a lot, So it means it doesn't care what you would pass in, it can be a variable, a function or a closure. But only tells do not need the parameter name when calling.

Comment: @SLN To elaborate on my comment: the parameter *name* is not used by the caller when the signature has `_:`. Like in `print(_:)`, you call it with `print(myStuff)` and not with `print(content: myStuff)` is what I meant.

Comment: Maybe one more question: Can I say this: How the `s1` and `s2` is actually handled is not so important. This is the API provided by the apple, just use it like this and everything is OK.